# Regex code parsing: how to search for "anything" within a search string

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I need to get several names (in this case "Abbi Glines") from code like this: (the code is the same each time apart from the url in the a href section)

```
<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">by </span><span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary"><a href="/Abbi-Glines/e/B0057RWP90/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_4?qid=1501506383&amp;sr=1-4" class="a-link-normal a-text-normal">Abbi Glines</a></span>
```

Here's what I've tried so far with regex:

```
(?<=by\ </span><span\ class="a-size-small\ a-color-secondary"><a(.*?)">).*?\w(?=</a></span>)
```

However, I get too many irrelevant matches.

How can I narrow it down to just find the persons' names in the code? The URL which comes before the class part is different each time so I can't search by that. That's why I tried the (.*?) thing.

I tried parsing the name out with just the last part of the code which comes before the name but there are too many other irrelevant matches.

Basically, how do I say search for a string where part of the string matches anything?

Comment: Please provide the output that you are getting and the expected output.

Comment: Is it something like:  <a href="/([^/]+)/  that you are looking for?  If so, I'll write up a detailed answer.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria and sniperd Thanks for answering!

Dhaval: Expected output - I just want to get the name before the closing </a> tag.

Sniperd: I'm not sure what the code should be... I just want it to say a href=ANYTHING and then the rest of the code. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418998/regex-code-parsing-how-to-search-for-anything-within-a-search-string/45421450#comment77801991_45418998), use,

```
href="/([^/]+)
```

Matches,

- href="/ literally
- [^/]+ will match everything till the next /

You will get the name in the first capturing group.